# Plotting lines - Google Maps APIv3

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps, gps, setinterval

What I want to achieve -

I have 2 variables - Latitude & Longitude, and both are updating in the background. I want to draw a line as per the variables are updating.

What I'm thinking -

1. Create an array path.
2. Create the line.
3. Update the path of the line using setInterval

The Code -

```
var poly;

function initialize() {

var Latitude
var Longitude

Latitude= {code that updates}
Longitude= {code that updates}

//create map
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 8,
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

var path = [];

poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
path: path,
geodesic: true,
strokeColor: '#FF0000',
strokeOpacity: 1.0,
strokeWeight: 2
});

poly.setMap(map);



var myVar = setInterval(function(){updateposition()},2000);

function updateposition(){
path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude,Longitude));
}
}
```

Problem - No line is appearing at all :(

Comment: You need to update the path property of the polyline (poly.setPath(path)) after updating the path.

Comment: And how can I do that in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the path property of the polyline (poly.setPath(path)) after updating the path.  Looking closer at your code, I am not sure how you expect Latitude and Longitude to update where they are (local to the initialize function).

```
function updateposition(){
  path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude,Longitude));
  poly.setPath(path);
}
```

[here is an example that updates the polyline from computed coordinates based on the time](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_updatingPolyline.html)

```
var poly;
var Latitude = null;
var Longitude = null;
var map = null;
var  path = [];

function initialize() {
  //create map
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(0,0)
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: path,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  poly.setMap(map);

  var myVar = setInterval(function(){updateposition()},2000);
}
function updateposition(){
   var date = new Date();
   var time = date.getMinutes()*60+date.getSeconds();
   Latitude= 45*Math.sin((time-1800)*Math.PI/1800.0)
   Longitude= (time/10)-180;
   path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude,Longitude));
   if (path.length == 1) {
     map.setCenter(path[0]);
     map.setZoom(8);
   } else {
     map.setCenter(path[path.length-1]);
   }
   poly.setPath(path);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```